# NodeJS readable streams

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I have this case that when having a stream created via `fs.createReadStream` and using `readable` event and `read(SIZE)` to consume it my stream from time to time somehow get stucked. Sometimes there are some more bytes in `stream.readableLength` but the readable events are not emitted and I can not read stream entirely. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
const myStream = fs.createReadStream('my-file', { highWaterMark = 1024 });

myStream.on('readable', () => {
  const chunk = myStream.read(1500);

  if (chunk !== null) {
    // DO SOME SYNC OR ASYNC ACTIONS
  }
})
```

Comment: Code please ...

Comment: @collapsar I think we can discuss it without the code. Is it possible that I have something in my stream.readableLength then I read part of that and no more readable events are emitted?

Comment: Or even better question: when are readable event emitted? When there is anything in the internal buffer? Or when something new has been added to the buffer since last readable event?

Comment: Clear questions with all the relevant code here have a very high chance of getting quick and accurate answers here.  Theoretical or conceptual questions without any code don't have nearly the success here as they require us guessing what it might be or could be.  I'm sure we can find your problem if you include all the relevant code.  With the information you have in your question so far, we can't even tell how you're really using the read stream at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 I edited my question by adding the example of my usage. Is it enough or should I even more context?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `data` event instead of the `readable` event?  In general, it is simpler to use.

Comment: Yes, I want to read chunks in specific size. AFAIK, data event can not guarantee me that the chunks it is providing me have the same size. Am I right?

Comment: The readable event doesn't guarantee that you get a whole chunk either.  It just delivers data that is available.

Comment: I think readable event + read(given_size) will guarantee that I will get chunks in size I want. Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @leszczu450 - Because `.read()` doesn't block waiting for that many bytes.  It just returns to you what's in the buffer already, up to the size you pass.  If the buffer contains less than your 1500 bytes, you'll get less than 1500 bytes.  This is what the doc says: ***The readable.read() method pulls some data out of the internal buffer and returns it. If no data available to be read, null is returned.***

Comment: @jfriend00 correct, but we are talking here about read(size) and not about read() and it bahaves differently imo

Comment: `read(size)` is NOT blocking.  It doesn't wait for 1500 bytes to be available.  If there's 100 bytes in the buffer and you do `.read(1500)`, you're going to get 100 bytes, not 1500.  If it works sometimes, that's just because your stream is flowing fast enough to give you what you want.  Go read the doc or look at the stream code to see.

Comment: That is not correct. If you do `.read(1500)` when buffer has 1000 bytes the `.read` function will return `null`.
+ I'm not saying `.read` is blocking.

Comment: To clarify - let's say HWM = 2000, inner buffer for now has 1000 and you want to read 1500 bytes. On fiest call to `.read(1500)` you will get null as a result, the HWM will be bumped to the nearest power of 2 greater than 1500 and you inner buffer will be able to get more data to itself. On another call to `.read(1500)` you will have enough data in inner buffer to read and this time you will get the buffer with the size you wanted to get.

Comment: Well, the doc is not clear on that point and the code (I looked at the code in the nodejs repository) is very, very complicated so one would have to design some tests to prove one way or the other.  Regardless, you don't show a `.read()` loop that keeps reading until you get `null` which can cause a stall which is the subject of my answer below.

Comment: What happens if you do `.read(1500)` and there's only 1000 bytes left in the entire stream?

Comment: I also checked the NodeJS repo codebase and tested in manually - read(1500) is behaving like I described above. However, I still don't get the need of having to call `.read` function. Shouldn't readable events be emitted regardless of my calls to `.read` function?

Comment: Answering your question - this time stream will let me read this last chunk in the size smaller than I wanted and no null will be returned. It behaves fine.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using the `data` event and letting the stream deliver all the data to you that way is simpler and less likely to run into problems.  That would be my recommendation unless there's a very specific reason you need to use the `readable` event and read the data yourself.

When you use the `readable` event and `myStream.read()`, you have to read everything there is until you get `null` back from the read indicating the buffer is empty now.  Otherwise, you will get stuck waiting for the next `readable` event that will not come.  From the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size) for `.read()`, it says this:

> The while loop is necessary when processing data with readable.read().
>   Only after readable.read() returns null, 'readable' will be emitted.

---

Here's a simple demonstration.  Just point this at a large file (say 100k):

```
const fs = require('fs');

let stream = fs.createReadStream("vlc-help.txt");

stream.on('readable', () => {
    let data = stream.read(10)
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I run this with it pointing at a 343,080 byte file, I see this output:

```
<Buffer ef bb bf 55 73 61 67 65 3a 20>
<Buffer 76 6c 63 20 5b 6f 70 74 69 6f>
```

I only get two readable events and then it is stalled.

---

When I put in the recommended `while()` loop like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let stream = fs.createReadStream("vlc-help.txt");

stream.on('readable', () => {
    let data;
    while (data = stream.read(10)) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I get a long stream of data until the entire file is read.

Comment: AFAIK, myStream.read(my_size) will return me null as long as there is not enough data in the inner buffer of myStream. If only inner buffer contains >= my_size the myStream.read(my_size) will not return me null but the chunk in the given size.

Comment: @leszczu450 - Regardless, you have to keep calling `.read()` until you get `null` back because you won't get another `readable` event until after you call `.read()` and get `null` back.  That issue seems like it's your current problem.  If you don't get `null` back, your reading will stall because you'll be waiting for a `readable` event that will never come. Also, that issue is completely independent from our other discussion about whether `.read(1500)` always gives you 1500 bytes or not.

Comment: Hmm I don't get it. So readable event is triggered by my `.read` calls?

Comment: Anyways, every call to `.read` can return me some data. So I don't want to do extra `.read` calls just to kick my stream so it emits readable events. I want to only read in once place and by one size. How about just emitting readable events like `myStream.emit('readable')` ?

Comment: @leszczu450 - The doc is pretty clear that once you get a `readable` event, you will NOT get another one until you call `.read()` enough times that you get `null` back.  The doc is very clear about that.  Yes, you may have to process more than one chunk.  That's just how the `readable` event works.  It's one of several reasons why it's more complicated to use `readable` than `data`.  But, if you want to use `readable`, you can - you just have to follow the rules.

Comment: How would you do it using `data` event instead of `readable`? Is it some good way of reading from stream chunk by chunk in specific chunk size?

Comment: @leszczu450 - With the `data` event you have to create your own buffer.  Collect data until you have the desired 1500 bytes, process that 1500, leave the rest of the data in your own buffer until you again have 1500 bytes accumulated.  At the `end` event, you  process what's left in the buffer.

Comment: Right, this seems like a lot of to reason about then. What I want to do it to lower the number of cached/buffered data by my Node program and readable event + read(size) seems like the only one by which I can avoid it totally.

Comment: @leszczu450 - Poking around in the readable stream source code, it looks like you can do a `.read(0)` after you've done your `.read(1500)` and that will enable things for another `readable` event.  I haven't tried it myself.  I don't personally know why it's a big deal to just put your `.read(1500)` in a while loop like the doc says to.  Just process each chunk that is ready in the loop.

Comment: But I'm still not fully convinced to the fact that these are my calls to `.read` which are responsible for  triggering readable events to be emitted. In my codebase I'm calling `read` only once and I get plenty of readable events. How does it work?

Comment: @leszczu450 - well the readable code is very complicated.  Go have a look if you want the explanation.  Meanwhile, I've offered two solutions.  I'm don't get why you're blocked on understanding why your know broken implementation sometimes works.  Just follow the doc and fix it.  I think I'm done here.  Offered two solutions.

Comment: "while" approach looks great. Thanks! But still, I do not know when is the readable event emitted? In the documentation there are two sentences which seems to be totally oposite to each other.
1. Only after readable.read() returns null, 'readable' will be emitted.
2. The 'readable' event is emitted when there is data available to be read from the stream.
So from 1. -  when there is no data of the given size, `.read(size)` returns me null which results in readable event emission and from 2. -  when there is some data in inner buffer the readable event is also emitted.

Comment: So it looks like every call to `.read(size)` triggers a readable event?

Comment: @leszczu450 - I added two simple tests to my answer that illustrate.  Please run them yourself and see.  All of this confusion is why using the `readable` event is a just not as straightforward as the `data` event, but you can certainly make it work just fine with the `while` loop.

Comment: Yep, the while loop example works great. It also works in my code. Thanks for that. The problem with all of the readable events was that I was not aware of the fact that this is the `read` call that triggers readable event to be emitted and not the opposite.

Comment: @leszczu450 - Since I think we've thoroughly answer your original question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: I want to stress this out: readable events will be emitted in 3 cases: 
1. On the very beginning of the stream consumption - attaching `.on`
2. On the very end of the stream consumtption - just before `end` event
3. On every call to `read` if only we stream.readableLength < stream.highWaterMark